# How to Export List of Paired Numbers to .csv File from Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, list, csv, printf

How can I export the following list to a .csv file using Bash?

```
1,100
2,100
3,100
4,100
5,100
```

I attempted this, but it takes too long for longer lists:

```
for i in $( seq 5)
    do printf "$i,0/n" >> file.csv
done
```

Comment: `printf '%d,100\n' {1..5} > file.csv` maybe? Avoids the loop.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Perfect...thanks!

Comment: see also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301437/how-to-create-a-column-with-zero-values-in-shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printf '%d,100\n' {1..5} > file.csv
```

Per Benjamin W.